# Web Socket - Sending Data back to the same client

Tags: html, websocket, stomp, spring-websocket, sockjs

I am using Spring 4 Web Sockets.
I have a STOMP Client. I want to send a message from a client to the STOMP Server and the STOMP Server should return the data back to the same client, which had send the data.

Here is my code for that. In WebSocketConfig, I am using queue as the message broker.

WebSocketConfig.java

```
package com.apple.store.datamonitor.dashboard.config;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketHandler;
//import org.springframework.web.socket.config.WebSocketMessageBrokerStats;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;

import com.apple.store.datamonitor.dashboard.websocket.ChartHandler;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {


    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
//        webSocketMessageBrokerStats.setLoggingPeriod(10 * 1000); // desired time in millis
    }
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/charthandler").withSockJS();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSocketHandler chartHandler() {
        return new ChartHandler();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/queue");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

}
```

ChartUpdateHandler.java.

The Code inside the greeting method is irrelevant for this question. Assume it is returning a simple object back to the client.

```
package com.apple.store.datamonitor.dashboard.websocket.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.MessageMapping;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.SendTo;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import com.apple.store.datamonitor.dashboard.domain.chart.BarData;
import com.apple.store.datamonitor.dashboard.domain.chart.BarDataWrapper;
import com.apple.store.datamonitor.dashboard.domain.report.Result;

@Controller
public class ChartUpdateController {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ChartUpdateController.class);

    @MessageMapping("/charthandler")
    @SendTo("/queue/update")
    public BarDataWrapper greeting(Result r) throws Exception {
//        Thread.sleep(3000); // simulated delay
        BarData data1 = new BarData(2, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2);
        data1.setYaxis("11-05-2016 01:00:00");
        List list1= new ArrayList<BarData>() {
            {
                add(data1);
            }
        };
        BarData data2 = new BarData(5, 10, 50, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3);
        data2.setYaxis("11-05-2016 01:00:00");
        List list2= new ArrayList<BarData>() {
            {
                add(data2);
            }
        };
        BarDataWrapper bd = new BarDataWrapper(list1, list2);
        return  bd;
    }

}
```

@MessageMapping(/charthandler) - it is for stomp clients to send the data to the server
@SendTo("/queue/update") - this is where server pushes the data back to the queue.Stomp clients will listen to the queue.

Here is my Javascript.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var socket = new SockJS('/datamonitordashboard/charthandler/');
      stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
      stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
        console.log('Connected: ' + frame);

        stompClient.subscribe('/queue/update', function(result) {
          console.log("l2 " + JSON.parse(result.body).l2List);

        });
      });
      $('#sendInfo').click(function(e) {
    sendData();
  });
    }

    function sendData() {
      var result = {
        title: "hello",
        sortOrder: "desc",
      };
      console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
      stompClient.send("/app/charthandler", {
        priority: 9
      }, JSON.stringify(result));
    }
```

After the DOM Is ready, i connect to the stomp server and i am binding a sendData() method with a bind. Now it sends the data to the stomp server.

Now I have opened 2 browsers open. From First Browser I click the send button, it pushes the result object to the StompServer and STOMP Server returns back the data to the second browser, which means, i see the log output in the second browser.
 console.log("l2 " + JSON.parse(result.body).l2List);

I want to send a message from a client(browser 1) to the STOMP Server and the STOMP Server should return the data back to the same client(browser 1)? How do it do that?

If i change the message broker to topic instead of queue, in my WebSocketConfig, it is sending the message to both the clients browser 1 and browser 2. I wanted to send the data back the same client?

config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");

Do i need to change the approach? Any solution for the above problem?